# Can't install my android app

Tags: android, installation

I downloaded my android app onto my phone to test it and when I try to install it the install just stops and says "Application not installed" or something like that. I'm not getting an error or anything so I can't figure out why it is doing this. Any ideas?

Comment: Got enough free space on your phone?

Comment: Have you uninstalled and tried again? I'm guessing the app exists on your phone, but is signed with a different signature (probably a debug key).

Comment: I assume it runs fine on the emulator?

Comment: yes to having space and it never actually installed completely.

Comment: Perhaps this thread might give you some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/application-not-installed-error-on-android

Comment: And yes it runs great on the emulator

Comment: Hmm...I haven't signed it yet since I am just testing it but I was able to install a friend's unsigned program.

Comment: @Seeshi_suin Have you checked the logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to see the error information in the log file. You can do that by:

1. Plugging in your device into the PC;
2. Run `adb logcat` to see the error you get when installing the application.

The problem may come from several places, therefore the best way to know what is happening is by checking the logs.

EDIT: I decided to include the official link of `adb` for the ones that are not familiar with it: [Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html)

Comment: @Seeshi_suin This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835925/unsigned-apk-can-not-be-installed) may also contain information that can be helpful for you.

Comment: Ah, I see. Needs to be signed! How inconvienient. Well thanks for your help! :D

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Applications -> Check 'Unknown Sources'

Comment: Then you might check out some of the comments posted to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem when I updated my manifest file.

I could load the program onto the phone, but the clicking its icon on the home screen gave me that error - it was probably uninstalled when I updated the manifest. However clicking the icon in the apps list worked fine.

Perhaps something similar happened in your case?

Comment: No it wouldn't even install at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an [APK Manager/Installer](https://market.android.com/details?id=jp.co.taosoftware.android.attachapkinstaller&feature=search_result)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using your .apk file and NOT trying to buy it on Android Market.

FYI Developers can not buy/download their own apps.