# Visual Studio Cordova Tools signed Release apk 'app not installed'

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

My Debug apk's install fine, but my signed release (or distribution) config apk's start to install and then give me the 'App not installed' message on my device. I would guess its not signing it properly? but it appears to. Any tips appreciated.

Comment: Have a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851873/application-not-installed-when-installing-an-self-signed-apk-on-sd-card

;)

Comment: Thanks! I had uninstalled it but once I uninstalled it for all users then I was good (is that new for lollipop?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are welcome,

PS: sorry! I can't comment (not enough reputation!) but it took, somehow, my previous answer as a comment, :))
So I put it here again:
The answer:

> If the two .apks have different signatures (Eclipse uses a debug
>   certificate), you will not be able to install/update with the new .apk
>   without removing the previous one.
>
> You can find more information about this [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851873/application-not-installed-when-installing-an-self-signed-apk-on-sd-card).