# I want to install an unsigned apk file on my mobile. what to do?

Tags: java, android, apk

I have built an app. I exported it through Eclipse APK.

I have the APK file. I want to send it to my dad (in another country, so wont be able to do a lot of technical stuff) so that he can install it and see my progress?

How do I do that without getting a dev account on playstore?

Comment: Send him over a `dropbox` or through mail dude!!

Comment: Mail the apk, how hard is that? We are better off than iOS.

Comment: The only thing he will have to do is enable: http://www.androidcentral.com/allow-app-installs-unknown-sources

Answer (score 4):

You cannot install an unsigned application on a phone. Check out this link to see how to sign the application: [unsigned APK can not be installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835925/unsigned-apk-can-not-be-installed)

Edit: This is from Google's website: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

> All applications must be signed. The system will not install an application 
>       on an emulator or a device if it is not signed.

Comment: You don't have to do that.  Just build it and copy the APK from /out

Comment: I know you can install applications that aren't from the Play Store, but don't they still have to be signed? Once it is signed, he can send the apk with dropbox or email and have anyone install it.

Comment: Nope.  I do it all the time.  As I say, just build and copy the APK.  Don't export.

Comment: So Simon, I just copy the apk file in the workspace folder and send that to my dad?

Answer (score 4):

You have to enable the install of unsigned application in the settings:

**Settings -> Application -> Unknown sources (Allow installation of non-Market applications)**

So you need to send him the file by mail or what ever and he needs to make the settings modification and install the file.

There is no need to sign the app in order to install it on a phone. if you ever ran this app in the emulator and `.apk` file will automatically created in the `\bin` folder of you project folder. just copy this file/ send it by mail for him to install.

Comment: Settings -> Application -> Unknown sources (Allow installation of non-Market applications)

Answer (score 0):

Your dad has to save the apk file in his device, so he will can open it.

After opening the application will can be installed.

So, send it by email, Dropbox, or other sharing service.

Your dad has to enable [installation from 'unknown sources'](http://www.androidcentral.com/allow-app-installs-unknown-sources).

Comment: my dad has the unknown sources thing ticked...Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Email your app to your dad and tell him to open that apk after below settings. [sign](http://www.androiddevelopment.org/tag/apk/) your app this way.

[image]

To create a signed .apk in Eclipse:

Select the project in the Package Explorer and select File > Export. 
Open the Android folder, select Export Android Application, and click 
Next. 
The Export Android Application wizard now starts, which will guide you 
through the process of signing your application, including steps for 
selecting the private key with which to sign the .apk (or creating a 
new keystore and private key). 
Complete the Export Wizard and your application will be compiled, 
signed, aligned, and ready for distribution."

[More Info on signing](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)