# Eclipse Installs .APK in the BIN Folder? Will not show up?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, api, apk

```
[2013-05-07 13:06:56 - final_app] Performing sync
[2013-05-07 13:06:56 - final_app] Automatic Target Mode: Several compatible targets. Please select a target device.
[2013-05-07 13:07:02 - final_app] Uploading final_app.apk onto device '015d256464281611'
[2013-05-07 13:07:14 - final_app] Installing final_app.apk...
[2013-05-07 13:07:18 - final_app] Success!
[2013-05-07 13:07:18 - final_app] \final_app\bin\final_app.apk installed on device
[2013-05-07 13:07:18 - final_app] Done!
```

Hi I have been pulling my hair out for the past 24 hours I am a newbie and added Google Maps after this I'm not sure what the issue has been I can no longer launch the app on my Nexus 7 or the AVD it does not show up, I have got my API key etc. but now the app installs  \final_app\bin\final_app.apk and I can not launch it any more I selected Googles APi everything should function properly, how do I launch the app again there is no icon what so ever. Could it be my manifest?

ANDROIDMANIFEST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.final_app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.final_app.splash_screen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" ></activity>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        <activity android:name="MainActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity_2"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity_3"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity_4"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity_5"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MySQLiteHelper"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

In short, I want to: Launch my app as it no longer shows up or starts on both my android device or AVD.

Comment: Your problem makes no sense at all... Please make an effort to describe it better.

Comment: Hi so sorry, what I want to solve is launching my app it does not launch it installs but nothing happens as you can see from the log above I do not know what to do I am stuck, thanks. I just want to test it like normal, but ever since I started the Google maps integration it no longer launches...

Comment: So it won't show up, whether you're building it with a debug key or your release key?

Comment: Is it showing lines with white background or just nothing happening ?

Comment: I am not sure but I used the Keytool to find my SHA-1 key from the debugkeystore file, I am a newbie so not familiar with the release key could that be the issue? I mean it should at the very least install on the AVD?

Comment: @Jeet nothing happens at all...

Comment: All was fine before I decided to integrate Google Maps now the install directory for the APK has changed to \final_app\bin\final_app.apk and the app never launches nor can I locate it on the device...

Comment: try to copy apk to your device and install it...and see if it shows anything, as your menifest looks fine, this problem normally comes when you passed APIKey wrong or something, did you turn on the Google Maps Api from their website for your account.

Comment: I have but it does not let me open it, and I have gone through various forums and answers could it be that it is unsigned? Is there a way to restore my app to the way it was without google maps etc?

Comment: @Jeet Yes API V2 and generated a key which I then put into my app and I changed API version to Googles API rather than 4.2.2

Comment: yes, you need to change setting in your device to allow installing apps that are unsigned from play store...so first change setting and then install your apk...

Comment: How would I change the settings? I am so sorry to pester you like this but I have been researching for hours on end and am stuck

Comment: check this link to fix your setting...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15743391/i-want-to-install-an-unsigned-apk-file-on-my-mobile-what-to-do

Comment: @Jeet I have the option enabled to allow unsigned packages to be installed

Comment: so now what is the issue...is it showing anything?

Comment: @Jeet it did not allow me to open the app

Comment: what is the error it is showing...? it is bit strange error

Comment: @Jeet it has the 'open' tab disabled so once I install it to the device I cannot open it? Is there anyway to revert back to my old application and remove all map related code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got your error, it was in the menifest file

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity"></activity>
```

it should be

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
```

or follow this menifest file

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/test"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ABC"
        android:label="@string/app_name"   android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".welcome" android:theme="@style/Custom" android:label="@string/app_name"  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
```

it should work i guess,..

Comment: Still the same problem do you suggest I go back and make a new project copy all files one bye one but leave out the google maps code?

Comment: yes, try that one..as you cannot revert back from here until unless you dont have old copy of your project...