# unsigned APK can not be installed - google maps app

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, apk, google-maps-api-2

I've developed an application that use Google Maps API v2.
I have installed it on my device directly from eclipse and it works fine.

Now I am trying to distribute my application to some people for testing, so I created unsigned APK file through Eclipse (Right click -> android tools -> export unsigned application package) and then an APK file was created.

I've copied the apk file to a clean phone (that never had tested my app before), but the installation fails each time i'm trying to install it, "the application is not installed" message appear and that's it. No further info.
(I have already checked the "Allow installation of non-Market application" on my phone)

Why is that??
Do I have to get the release API key and sign my app in order for it to work??
Please help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835925/unsigned-apk-can-not-be-installed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do I have to get the release API key and sign my app in order for it to work?

No. However, an unsigned APK is not going to help you. You can take the APK you already have from Eclipse (signed with the debug signing key) and distribute it. You can find that APK file in `bin/` of your project directory.

The debug signing key is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).

Comment: Ok, I just tried to install the apk file from that bin/ folder and it worked!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This has everything that you need to do to put something up on the app store or install on a phone! The app has to be signed

[Signing an app](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Comment: But I DO NOT want to publish my app in the app store just yet. I just want an apk file that i'm able to install....

Comment: I just edited the answer as you replied! Anyway the comment on your question actually has a way mentioned to sign your app in a quick simple manner to enable installation on devices!

Comment: @TamarCohen An unsigned app cannot be installed on the phone. You need a signed APK to install on phone even though you are not ready to put on Play Store. Unsigned app is good only for emulator

Comment: @Sundeep: An unsigned app is not even good for the emulator. An APK must be signed for any Android environment to run it. Whether it is signed by the debug signing key (what you normally get from Eclipse) or signed via a production signing key is up to the developer.

Comment: @TamarCohen bottomline is you have to sign your app! Either follow the link I have given or the instructions at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835925/unsigned-apk-can-not-be-installed as Sundeep mentioned

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks! Any idea what it is good for that Eclipse provided an option to export it?

Comment: I think @CommonsWare has given the easiest solution! You can disregard my answer

Comment: @Sundeep: The export is for signing outside of Eclipse, such as using a production signing key.