# android app works on emulator but is not getting installed on real device with equivalent os versions

Tags: android, performance

i have made 2 android app which work fine on the emulator with android 4.1.2(i.e. API level 16)
but when i try to install them on a real device with android 4.1.2 both the apps do not get installed and error message "application not install" is show...

one of those app is targeted for API 18 and minimum API supported is 11
other app is targeted for API 18 and minimum API supported is 8

Comment: Collect logcat during the installation attempt.  You may need to do this from the terminal / command window rather than through an IDE like Eclipse - at the least, do it without any filtering.

Comment: can you please past the log cat here..

Comment: please uninstall all/any previous versions of your app from the device. This sometimes may happen when there is a conflict in the package names of one or the other apps. Also, you can try checking "Allow applications from unknown sources".

Comment: i found out the answer,thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and here it is!

If you are unable to connect your device to your computer due to lack of drivers or other stuff you can copy the ".apk" file which is located in the project folder.

To install the app on a 'physical' device do the following

1. Locate and copy the .apk file of the app to the device. For locating the apk [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620366/apk-location-in-new-android-studio) might help.
2. Go to Settings -> Security and check 'Allow installation from unknown sources' (this step only required if u export the app without signing it). If it still gives some issues check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835925/unsigned-apk-can-not-be-installed)
3. Locate the apk in the device and install it

Though i would recommend to try/debug the app in virtual device or a physical device which is connected through USB, since that would help you to catch the log created by [logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html)