# Android APK not installed in the device

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

A few months back I have sent Android APK to my client. At that time it was installed successfully but the same APK doesn't want to install (Application not installed) now on any device.

Again I have generated a new unsigned APK but that one also not installed any device. So I generated a signed APK now and it is installed successfully in all the devices.

Note: I have generated the APK using Eclipse.

Has there been any changes in Android APK creation?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you told us the actual error.

Comment: while installing the apk i got this message "Application not installed"

Comment: What happens if you completely remove the application first, and then try to install the unsigned version

Comment: did you use apk under `project\bin\` folder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [unsigned APK can not be installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835925/unsigned-apk-can-not-be-installed)

Comment: I faced this problem on yesterday @youngjae

Comment: Have you enabled "allow installation of apps from unknown sources" option in your security options

Comment: Yes i enabled that option also but not installing the APK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing any problem with APK creation using Eclipse.

If already Unsigned APK installed in the Device. 
   Signed APK will not install. It gives Error.

If already signed APK installed in the Device.
   Unsiged APK will not install. It gives Error.

If any APK installed in the Device, don't directly install from Eclipse. Uninstall already installed APK, then try to install new APK

Connect that device in your Eclipse code, check the Logcat for error logs. Sure some error exception will throw. Then you can easily solve this problem.

Comment: How you are trying to install APK..? Signed APK..? Unsigned APK..? Directly from Eclipse..? In Emulator..? In Device..?

Comment: Answer this : Signed APK..?  Unsigned APK..? Directly from Eclipse..? In Emulator..? In Device..? Not from Eclipse means, How are you are installing APK..?

Comment: i kept the APK in server then through url i will download APK into device and installing