# Visual Studio 2015, cordova project, apk build cannot be installed on Android Device

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

Strange issue! My Visual Studio Comunity 2015 Update 2 no longer builds installable apk's.

When I try to install the apk (for testing purposes) on my Android device (and I've tested on 3 different phones) I get an error:

*There was an error parsing the package.*

When building the project everything is ok, an apk file apears in the Release folder. The name of the file is always *android-release-unsigned.apk*

I think it's a setting in the Environment wich prevents the apk's to be installed on the device.

I tried with new, empty Cordova Project and I have the same issue.
However in the Emulators the apps are running very well.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to sign the APK. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835925/unsigned-apk-can-not-be-installed#4836014

Answer (score 0):

I guess you cant install any unsigned apk's which is in the release folder. If it is a release you must sign the apk 1st. And other thing is, if it is for testing purpose you may go for a debug apk. It should work. Good luck