# xamarin android apk installs on emulator but not on device

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, apk

I have an existing android application which is written in Xamarin Android.  when I  Adhoc distribute the APK I am able to install the APK on an emulator. However when I try to install the apk on a device I get the following error

Starts installing and then Application cannot be installed. USB debugging enabled and allow application from unknown sources is enabled.

My project properties look like this

[image: Application]
[image]
[image]

Package signing is blank i.e, default

When I do build acrhive and save the apk.  I can take the apk and run on an emulator on a different machine however when i try to install the apk on a device it fails with error 'Application not installed'

I am really new to this guys, any help is greatly appreciated. I bet i am missing something simple.

Comment: silly question, but do you have enough space on your device? Also what Android device do you have? I know LG has issues with being able to deploy on it.

Comment: That's ok no question is a silly question imao. Yes, I am using Android OS 9 Samsung. I tried it on Andoroid 8 and same issue but emulator OS 8 and OS 9 no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out guys. You have to go into play store settings and click play protect and settings. Disable the slider and the app installs.

Answer (score 1):

You should sign your APK. [Unsigned APK cannot be installed on the real device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835925/unsigned-apk-can-not-be-installed). Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/?tabs=windows) how to sign Xamarin Android app.

Comment: Yes i have already done this. Thank you. I managed to get it working see my answer.